# REGEXP_EXTRACT with String Value in Bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, extract, regexp-replace

I want to extract words in a column, the column value looks like this:'p-fr-youtube-car'. And they should all be extracted to their own column.

**INPUT**:

```
p-fr-youtube-car
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**:

```
Country = fr
Channel = youtube
Item = car
```

I've tried below to extract the first word, but can't figure out the rest.What RegEx will achieve my desired output from this input? And how can I make it not case sensative fr and FR will be the same.

`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r"^p-([a-z]*)") AS Country`

Comment: You may use `([^-]+)` to match parts between hyphens. To get `youtube`, `^p-[^-]+-([^-]+)` and to get `car`, use `^p-[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)`.

Comment: Did you mean like this? REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'(?i)^p-[^-]+-([^-]+)([a-z]*)') AS Channel,  I get error: Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group

Comment: I wrote the exact patterns, no need to meddle with them. `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'^p-[^-]+-([^-]+)')` and `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'^p-[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)')`. Use them *separately*.

Comment: Ah okej, great now I understand. Thank you. That worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[^-]+` to match parts between hyphens and only capture what you need to fetch.

To get strings like `youtube`, you can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'^p-[^-]+-([^-]+)')
```

To get strings like `car`, you can use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'^p-[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)')
```

So, `[^-]+` matches one or more chars other than `-` and `([^-]+)` is the same pattern wrapped with a capturing group whose contents `REGEXP_EXTRACT` actually returns as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named groups.

Example Regex:

```
p-(?P<Country>[a-z]*)\-(?P<Channel>[a-z]*)\-(?P<Item>[a-z]*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/fKoBIn/3

[image]

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, I've edited regex and link to be valid Golang regex.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work in bigquery, not sure if that's supported since I think I need to add As Contry to create the column for example.. I get the error" Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group" When I add 'REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'^p-(?P<Country>[a-z]*)\-(?P<Channel>[a-z]*)\-(?P<Item>[a-z]*)$') as test,'

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I would recommend use of SPLIT in cases like yours

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CampaignName, 
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS Country,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS Channel,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS Item
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(CampaignName, '-') AS parts)])
```

if to apply to sample data from  your question - the output is

```
Row CampaignName        Country     Channel     Item     
1   p-fr-youtube-car    fr          youtube     car
```

Meantime, if for some reason you are required to use Regexp - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CampaignName, 
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS Country,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS Channel,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS Item
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(CampaignName, r'(?:^|-)([^-]*)') AS parts)])
```